# Tansformar uma resposta JSON em uma lista e exibir os dados na tela com IONIC

Tags: typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Boa tarde pessoal, sempre que tenho alguma duvida corro aqui na esperança de vocês me ajudarem e sempre consigo respostas positivas, desde já meu muito obrigado.

Bom, estou com um probleminha aqui (não tenho muita afinidade com typescript). Eu estou recebendo um objeto em Json como resposta e preciso colocar esses itens neste array e passar pra um componente na tela.

O retorno Json

```
[
    {
        "distancia": "0.0000000000",
        "resultado": "9551, FRANCISCO CAVALCANTE LACERDA-LACERDOPOLIS, G019688"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.0000000000",
        "resultado": "9552, FRANCISCO CAVALCANTE LACERDA-LACERDOPOLIS, G019689"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.0000000000",
        "resultado": "9553, FRANCISCO CAVALCANTE LACERDA-LACERDOPOLIS, Z118507"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.0000000000",
        "resultado": "9554, ROSA DOS VENTOS-LACERDOPOLIS, Z013630"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.0900949795",
        "resultado": "9557, ALTEMAR DUTRA-HELIOPOLIS, G019695"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.0900949795",
        "resultado": "9558, ALTEMAR DUTRA-HELIOPOLIS, G019693"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.0900949795",
        "resultado": "9550, FRANCISCO CAVALCANTE LACERDA-LACERDOPOLIS, G019687"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.0900949795",
        "resultado": "9556, ROSA DOS VENTOS-LACERDOPOLIS, G019573"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.0900949795",
        "resultado": "9555, ROSA DOS VENTOS-LACERDOPOLIS, G019694"
    },
    {
        "distancia": "0.1274138708",
        "resultado": "9559, ALTEMAR DUTRA-HELIOPOLIS, G019572"
    }
]
```

Onde preciso exibir os dados json

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Postes</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="postes">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let lista_postes of lista_postes; let i = index;" value={‌{lista_postes}}>{‌{ i + lista_postes}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Método que submet a informação ao servidor e recebe como retorno um Json, que teria que popular esta lista.

```
submitCadastroNotification() {
  var _link = 'http://www.baseterritorial.com.br/desktop/projetos/baselumina/baselumina.app.php?baselumina_mobile=';
  var _data = JSON.stringify({
    acao: "localizar",
    uuid: this.uuid,
    barramento: this.barramento,
    latitude: this.latitude,
    longitude: this.longitude,
  });
  console.log(_data);
  //iniciando conexão HTTP para cadastro do usuário via JSON
  this.http.post(_link + _data)
    .subscribe(_data => {
      this.data.response = _data._body;
      this.lista_postes.push(this.data.response);

      console.log(this.lista_postes);

      //console.log(this.data.response);
    }, error => {
      console.log("Ocorreu algum erro!");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parece que seu problema está nesta linha:

`<ion-option *ngFor="let lista_postes of lista_postes; let i = index;" value={‌{lista_postes}}>{‌{ i + lista_postes}}</ion-option>`

O *ngFor funciona como um foreach em outras linguagens, neste caso o `let lista_postes` define uma variável chamada `lista_postes` para cada lista_postes, algo de estranho?
Pois é, o nome da variável do for, (`let lista_postes`) deveria ter um nome diferente, assim podendo acessar cada um das chaves do objeto no array, por exemplo:

`<ion-option *ngFor="let poste of lista_postes; let i = index;" value={‌{poste.distancia}}>{‌{ i +' '+ post.resultado}}</ion-option>`

Mais informações: https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf